# available CRAN vignettes

Tags: r, data.table, cran, vignette

There's the `available.packages()` function to list all packages available on CRAN.  Is there a similar function to find all available vignettes?  If not how would I get a list of all vignettes and the packages they're associated with?

As a corner case to keep in mind the `data.table` package has 3 vignettes associated with it.

**EDIT:  Per Andrie's response I realize I wasn't clear.  I know about the vignette function for finding all the available local vignettes, I'm after a way to get all the vignettes of all packages on CRAN.**

Comment: You could parse (e.g. with `XML` and `RCurl`) all package indices on CRAN although I am quite sure sysadmins would not love this idea there.

Comment: I seem to recall looking at this in response to some SO question (can't find it now) and deciding that since the information isn't included in the output of `available.packages()`, nor in the result of applying `readRDS` to `@CRAN/web/packages/packages.rds` (a trick from Jeroen Ooms), I couldn't think of a non-scraping way to do it ...

Comment: This would be part of a package that is intended for CRAN so a scraping method is not the best approach unless... I could scrape once and store the information as a data set in the package that gets updated with each new version of the package.  A possibility perhaps.

Comment: @BenBolker could you add that comment as an answer so I can accept it?  Not the answer I was hoping for but thought may be the probable outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to recall looking at this in response to some SO question (can't find it now) and deciding that since the information isn't included in the output of `available.packages()`, nor in the result of applying `readRDS` to `@CRAN/web/packages/packages.rds` (a trick from Jeroen Ooms), I couldn't think of a non-scraping way to do it ...

Here's my scraper, applied to the first 100 packages (leading to 44 vignettes)

```
pkgs <- unname(available.packages()[, 1])[1:100]
vindex_urls <- paste0(getOption("repos"),"/web/packages/", pkgs, 
    "/vignettes/index.rds", sep = "")
getf <- function(x) {
      ## I think there should be a way to do this directly
      ## with readRDS(url(...)) but I can't get it to work
    suppressWarnings(
              download.file(x,"tmp.rds",quiet=TRUE))
    readRDS("tmp.rds")
}
library(plyr)
vv <- ldply(vindex_urls,
            .progress="text",
            function(x) {
                if (inherits(z <- try(getf(x),silent=TRUE),
                    "try-error")) NULL else z
            })
tmpf <- function(x,n) { if (is.null(x)) NULL else
                            data.frame(pkg=n,x) }
vframe <- do.call(rbind,mapply(tmpf,vv,pkgs))
rownames(vframe) <- NULL
head(vframe[,c("pkg","Title")])
```

There may be ways to clean this up/make it more compact, but it seems to work OK.  Your scrape once/update occasionally strategy seems reasonable. Or if you wanted you could scrape daily (or weekly or whatever seems reasonable) and save/post the results somewhere publicly accessible, then include a function with that URL hard-coded in the package ... or even create a nicely formatted HTML table, with links, that the whole world could use (and then add Viagra ads to the page, and $$PROFIT$$ ...)

**edit**: wrapped both the download and the readRDS in a function, so I can wrap the whole thing in `try`

Comment: I think I'm going to scrape with this or a modified version and include the output as a data set in the package.  Thank you though i'll probably forgo the Viagra advertisement.

Comment: I tried the function above and ran into a problem.  I eliminated `, sep = ""` as you're using `paste0`.  But when I try to run the v v portion.  It stops at 20% and gives me the following error: `Error in the readRDS (tmp.rds) : error reading from the connection`  Any ideas on how to overcome this?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know.  Maybe there's a corrupted index.rds file somewhere?  You could put in yet another `try` statement around the `readRDS` in order to skip over it ... because the function uses `ldply`, it doesn't have access to the name of the current package being processed; it might be worth sucking it up and using a `for` loop for greater transparency ...

Comment: This allows me to keep trucking but then throws up an error: `Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) : 
  Results must be all atomic, or all data frames`

Comment: You need to check the results of `try(readRDS(...))` and return `NULL` on an error. I will try an edit.

Answer (score 2):

The functions `vignette()` and `browseVignettes()` list all vignettes of packages installed on your machine.

```
vignette(package="data.table")

Vignettes in package ‘data.table’:

datatable-faq                         Frequently asked questions (source, pdf)
datatable-intro                       Quick introduction (source, pdf)
datatable-timings                     Timings of common tasks (source, pdf)
```

`browseVignettes()` is especially helpful since it creates a web page with hyperlinks:

```
browseVignettes(package="data.table")

Vignettes found by browseVignettes(package = "data.table")

Vignettes in package data.table

Frequently asked questions - PDF  R  LaTeX/noweb 
Quick introduction - PDF  R  LaTeX/noweb 
Timings of common tasks - PDF  R  LaTeX/noweb
```

Comment: Thanks Andrie, I'm actually after a complete list of vignettes that CRAN has to offer, not just the locally installed packages.  I think this may be a bit more difficult than I had hoped.